# metamask token transfer

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet

I am trying to transfer several tokens from my metamask using MEW, and I have eth to cover the gas, and I followed all instructions many times, but every time it fails to transfer. Anyone have any advice?
thanks.

Comment: out of gas error or what?

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash or did it not get that far?

Comment: We need the error message to help you. When you say it fails. What is the message telling you that it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Transferring tokens usually costs a lot more gas than simply sending eth. This is because you must call the transfer function on the tokens smart contract. What you will need to do is increase gas limit. (See images below on how to do that).

I recommend checking https://ethgasstation.info/ for what you should set the gas price to.

If that's not the issue it could be something with the contract itself in which it's out of your hands.

Sorry this is my time answering and I'm trying to give you as much information as I can based on your question.

[image: click this icon]
[image: set the gas]